# How to configure wso2 with elastic apm?

Tags: wso2, elastic-apm

Has anyone already tried to connect wso2 production with elastic apm server ?
I have done this

```
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -javaagent:/tmp/apm-agent.jar"
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Delastic.apm.service_name=wso2am"                                
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Delastic.apm.server_urls=http://192.168.1.156:8200"
```

But i dont have the http request of the API in the APM in kibana

Comment: hi, add please 
-Delastic.apm.application_packages=org.example - here your application package
 and  
-Delastic.elastic.apm.log_level=DEBUG 
confiugurations. And try it out. And can you share your logs, there are should be more informative information?